# Javascript returns value function

Tags: javascript

For example, when calling a function, let's give it two values. Let the first value be the starting value and the second value the maximum value. When you call that function, increase it from the first value to the second value every second.

```
let a;
function MyCount(number, maxNumber) {

    setInterval(() => {
        if (number == maxNumber) {
            return false;
        } else {
            a = number++;
            return a;
        }
    }
        , 100)
}

console.log(MyCount(10, 40));
```

Comment: your function doesn't `return` anything ... you need a `return` statement somewhere if you want to `return` something, that's how functions work - though, I doubt you can call a function ONCE and return a value multiple times - that's also not how functions work

Comment: Add some explanation please

Comment: what do you want `console.log(MyCount(10, 40));` to output to the console? given that it will output to the console once and once only

Comment: For example, when calling a function, let's give it two values. Let the first value be the starting value and the second value the maximum value. When you call that function, increase it from the first value to the second value every second.

Comment: I have difficulty explaining because my English is weak

Comment: @HrushikeshDharmadhikari

Comment: one second is 1000, not 100

Comment: Oh okay @Revan Zakaryali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to call a function in which you will enter two number parameters.

The first one will be a start value

If the first one is equal to the second on then you want to log false to the console.

else you want to add one to the number and log the updated number again and retry the process

If I am correct then here is your answer

```js
function MyCount(number, maxNumber) {
    var i = setInterval(()=>{
        if (number == maxNumber) {
            console.log("false");
            window.clearInterval(i)
            return;

        } else {
            number++;
            console.log(number);
        }
    },100)

}

MyCount(10,15)
```

And also number++ is equal to number = number + 1